# Xbox360 Multi-Platform Emulator

Tags: emulator

I'm looking for a free/paid Emulator for older than PSX consoles. I have no issue with building it myself as long as it does not involve autotools.  It can be from the Xbox360 Gold Live Marketplace.

Comment: Questions seems rather cryptic - what do you mean by "360"? The xbox 360? What's the gold market?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Fixed

Comment: You need to be much more specific here. Are you looking for a emulator that emulates every console launched before the PSX? And how the Xbox Marketplace is related with it?

Comment: @FabioSilva Yes thats exactly what I put in the question.  And if I can get that such emulator from Xbox Marketplace, then I am ok with that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: there are no emulators for the Xbox 360 that you can download from the marketplace. You will always need a [Jtag](http://free60.org/wiki/SMC_Hack) or [RGH](http://free60.org/wiki/Reset_Glitch_Hack) console to run them.

This having been said, [Retroarch 360](http://www.emucr.com/2014/03/retroarch-360-v1002.html) is an Xbox360 port of the famus Retro Arch multi-system emulator for the 360. It can run:

- Genesis Plus GX
- Genesis Plus GX
- SNES9x Next
- VBA Next
- NEStopia
- FCEUmm
- Mednafen PCE Fast
- Mednafen NGP
- Mednafen VB
- Mednafen Wonderswan
- Prboom
- NX Engine (Cave Story)
- Tyrquake
- FInal Burn Alpha
- Gambatte
- MAME 2003 (0.78) NEW!

Alternatively, you can find a list of single-system emulators [here](http://dev360.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Emulators)